# for in loop only saving the last element in Parse. SWIFT

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop, parse-platform

I am doing a for in loop on an array of PFUsers, then inside that for in loop I want to be able to set key fields for each users which has been looped through. For some reason it only saves the last element of the for in loop. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong? code:

```
var user2ObjId = ["N7xqk8oFJx", "Q5lPX2DUmP", "mfkO8iypTB"]

let userQuery = PFUser.query()
        userQuery.whereKey("objectId", containedIn: user2ObjId)
        let foundUsers = userQuery.findObjects()
        if foundUsers.count > 0 {
            let addRoomObject = PFObject(className: "Room")
            for user in foundUsers {

                addRoomObject["user1"] = PFUser.currentUser()
                addRoomObject["user2"] = user

                addRoomObject.addObject(2, forKey: "questionNumbers")
                addRoomObject["matchCount"] = 1

            }
            addRoomObject.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                if success == true {
                   // println("Added new users to room")
                }
            })
        }
```

in the `user2ObjId` array the only one what saves is the `mfkO8iypTB`. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the for-in loop, you are setting properties into the same instance, but you're saving when exiting from the loop, which happens when the last element in `foundUsers` has been processed - that explains why the last object only is saved.

You can use [saveAllInBackground](http://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/saveAllInBackground:block:)

```
var array = [PFObject]()
for user in foundUsers {
  let addRoomObject = PFObject(className: "Room")

  addRoomObject["user1"] = PFUser.currentUser()
  addRoomObject["user2"] = user

  addRoomObject.addObject(2, forKey: "questionNumbers")
  addRoomObject["matchCount"] = 1

  array.append(addRoomObject)     
}

PFObject.saveAllInBackground(array, block({ (success: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in
   if success == true {
       // println("Added new users to room")
   }
})
```

Comment: Nope, I also tried this, The result is still the same. It saves the final element only.

Comment: @HenryBrown: ok, see updated answer - I apologize in advance if I've made any mistake, I've written the code in a normal text editor, so it's highly probable I wrote something wrong :)

Comment: Good answer and it should work, but it doesn't? I have println the `array` array variable you have just set and it showing the same user three times inside the array, instead of three different users at it should??

Comment: For some reason it is adding the same user three times rather then iterating through and adding each one individually? I have no idea why thou

Comment: That's weird - could you check if `foundUsers` actually contains 3 different users?

Comment: Ahhh I've got it! my fault the `let addRoomObject = PFObject(className: "Room")` was still outside my for in loop. I have now put it inside and it is working! thanks for you help Antonio!

Comment: :D you're welcome - glad it's fixed now. Still using the old method or the new `saveAllInBackground`? (which is much better)

Comment: I am using the `saveAllInBackground`, never used it before so thanks for the tip, will come in handy in future.